# Where is the 'tz' time zone database physically stored in the Oracle JVM for Java 8?

Tags: java, timezone

For the [Oracle implementation of Java 8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) for Mac OS X (and Linux and Windows), where is the [`tz` time zone database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database) physically stored within the JDK/JRE?

I would like to find the actual file for inspection.

I have located the JVM on a Mac with El Capitan in `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_92.jdk`. But my perusal of its contents did not reveal any 'tz' file that I could recognize.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Java 8, the tz file is

```
jre/lib/tzdb.dat
```

See also the [Timezone Updater Tool](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tzupdater-readme-136440.html). Which says, in part,

> For JDK 8 and later family versions:
>
> - Locate the `'tzdb.dat'` file under the modified JAVAHOME/jre/lib directory. This is the newer data file.
> - Locate the `'tzdb.dat.<oldtzdataversion>'`; file in the same JAVAHOME/jre/lib directory. This is the replaced, older data file.
> - Obtain the currently installed timezone data version from the command `java -jar tzupdater.jar -V`.
> - Rename the current `'tzdb.dat'` file to something like `'tzdb.dat.<newtzdataversion>'`, or whatever version was given by the command in step 3. Ensure this name does not conflict with the older data files.
> - Rename the older data file to `'tzdb.dat'`.
> - Validate the change in currently active timezone data by executing `java -jar tzupdater.jar -V`.
> - Restart applications on this JDK/JRE instance as desired.

Comment: For completeness, [this is the code in Oracle JDK](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/sun/util/calendar/ZoneInfoFile.java#251) that reads this file.